# Python warnings.warn() not returning anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings, jupyter

I'm using `warnings.warn()`, together with a print, but the warnings are not returned:

```
if[1!=2]:
    print('Error')
    warnings.warn('Warning!')
#returns:  Error
```

I'm using Jupyter. Would appreciate if someone could assist

Comment: Are you also looking at your error output? (stderr). `warnings.warn` probably writes there while print writes on stdout

Comment: It prints it out in my console. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031783/hide-all-warnings-in-ipython#9031848 maybe there's something in your jupyter startup files

Comment: Works fine for me. Cannot reproduce the issue. See these posts, maybe there is something related to your issue: [Configure IPython to show warnings all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27787677/7851470), [Jupyter notebook does not print logs to the output cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35936086/7851470)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37979724/3465514 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40667761/3465514: two good comments that explain how warning display is handled, it might have been called already and the following calls are muted

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. This was working fine a bit ago, suddenly it stopped working.

@gst : terminal shows nothing there when running this jupyter cell.

Thanks to your links, I solved it with `warnings.filterwarnings('always')`. I guess I will need to include it in my preamble.

Also, I've voted to close since [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787677/configure-ipython-to-show-warnings-all-the-time](this) was the same question (and solution)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure IPython to show warnings all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787677/configure-ipython-to-show-warnings-all-the-time)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue.
My solution was to switch to python's `logging` package.

```py
import logging
logging.warning("Warning!")
```

It printed to the console on my end!